# Can you get the year from epoch in SQLite with one function?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Right now I'm doing

```
SELECT strftime('%Y',datetime(epoch,'unixepoch')) FROM tableX
```

to get the year.  And it works... though I really thought there was a way to get the year straight from the epoch with one function, not two.

Comment: wouldn't that just be 1970?

Comment: Maybe I should have specified if it's not clear, that "epoch" is a column in table that has a specific epoch time

Answer (score 0):

All date/time functions accept the same [modifiers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
SELECT strftime('%Y', epoch, 'unixepoch') FROM tableX
```